# How to open PDF in background with HTMLLoader?

Tags: apache-flex, pdf, actionscript

I created an application with Flex and it open large PDF file, so when show PDF file it is too slow. Anybody, who know a solution which open PDF in background with HTMLLoader?

Thanks for read this question and reply.

Answer (score 0):

You **can not** run [multiple-Threads/background-process](http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2008/01/threads_in_actionscript_3.html) in action script, a way around is pseudo-threading, but wont work in every situation,

For you problem i think you should manage in wrapper(HTML,JSP,ASPX) using multiple SWF, mean separate SWF to load PDF

Hopes that helps